# How do I show a value from model association in an ExtJS grid?

Tags: extjs, model, associations, grid-layout

I am trying to draw a grid where each line is a stock's performance for a single day. In my data structures, I have a `Date`, a `Stock`, and a `Stock Price` resource. The store attached to my grid is the `Stock Price` store.

So, to the best of my understanding, my biggest problem is that when the grid cell renderers, I need to already have the value, or I need to have a blocking function to *get* a value.

When I use the `getStore()` magic function, I'm told the record doesn't know about it (undefined method). I'm assuming it's 'cause the record doesn't have the same functionality as a standalone model.

I see a few ways out of this:

1. Customise the grid and/or store so that when a load happens, all the related rows are loaded at the same time.
2. Create a callback in the renderer, and change the cell value afterwards, but I'm ot exactly sure how to do this. I don't actually want to change the cell value (`StockId`), just the visible output (`Symbol`).
3. Change my API to match my view.

Summing these up: #1 seems like a lot of work for a seemingly simple outcome. I keep trying to use the associations, but I'm finding they're not really useful for anything aside from little things here and there, and certainly not for lots of data. #2 I don't quite know where to begin at the moment; and #3 seems like massive overkill, and will generally ruin my server side as I will mean a few more joins, and more complexity when saving records as well.

So, two part question:

1. Does anyone know how to load a value from an associated model in a grid?
2. If not, to pique my curiosity, what sort of things are associations used for in any case where there's lots of data to deal with on screen? Lot's of data seems to be the reason to use Ext vs jQueryUI or some other UI framework, so I'm wondering what the associations are for.

**Model - Stock Price**

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.model.StockPrice', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty : 'StockPriceId',
    fields : [ {
        name : 'StockId',
        type : 'int'
    }, {
        name : 'Open',
        type : 'float'
    }, {
        name : 'Close',
        type : 'float'
    }, {
        name : 'DateId',
        type : 'date'
    }],
    proxy : {
        type : 'rest',
        url : '/api/stock.price'
    },
    reader : {
        type : 'json'
    },
    associations : [ {
            type : 'hasOne',
            model : 'MyApp.model.Date',
            primaryKey : 'DateId',
            foreignKey: 'DateId'
    },{
        type : 'hasOne',
        model : 'MyApp.model.Stock',
        primaryKey : 'StockId',
        foreignKey : 'StockId'
    } ]
});
```

**Model - Stock**

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Stock', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty : 'StockId',
    fields : [ {
        name : 'StockId',
        type : 'int'
    }, {
        name : 'Symbol',
        type : 'string'
    } ],
    proxy : {
        type : 'rest',
        url : '/api/stock'
    },
    reader : {
        type : 'json'
    },
    associations : [ {
        type : 'hasMany',
        model : 'MyApp.model.StockPick',
        primaryKey : 'StockId',
        foreignKey : 'StockId'
    }]
});
```

**Model - Date**

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Date', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ 'DateId', 'Date' ]
});
```

**Store - Stock Price**

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.store.StockPrice', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model : 'MyApp.model.StockPrice',
    remoteSort : true,
    remoteFilter : true,
    pageSize : 5,
    autoLoad : true
});
```

**View - Stock Price**

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.panel.StockData', {
    extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    store : 'MyApp.store.StockPrice', 
    columns : [
            {
                text : 'Symbol',
                flex : 1,
                sortable : false,
                hideable : false,
                dataIndex : 'StockId',
                renderer : function(stockId, metadata, stockPriceRecord) {
                     // What goes in here? PROBLEM POINT
                     MyApp.model.Stock.load(stockId, function() {
                         // ... some callback
                     });
                     // OR
                     return stockPriceRecord.getStock().get('Symbol');
                }
            },
            {
                text : 'Open',
                flex : 1,
                dataIndex : 'Open',
                renderer : 'usMoney'
            },
            {
                text : 'Close',
                flex : 1,
                dataIndex : 'Close',
                renderer : 'usMoney'
            },
            {
                text : 'Volume',
                flex : 1,
                dataIndex : 'Volume'
            }]
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your only real option to display data from an associated model in a grid is to use a custom renderer function on the column. This will not change any values; it will simply render the desired output into the cell.

Now, as for implementing that renderer function: I would start by removing the proxies from the models and instead create stores for each model and allow the stores to manage the proxies -- then, attach the store for `Stock` as a listener on the store for `StockPrice` to listen for the `datachanged` event. When the data of the `StockPrice` store changes, you should grab every unique referenced `Stock` id and then tell the `Stock` store to request a payload of stocks with those ids.

That may mean altering your API a little bit to support a SQL `IN(...)` behind the scenes, but by leaving the joins to the client side you will put less stress on your server side.

In short, you need to use a little bit of all three ideas you came up with in order to best achieve your goal.

Comment: Took me a lot of custom code, but I got it. I found that I had to call 'render' after the `Stock` store had loaded, to then redraw the symbols, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Custom code indeed, guess that's why it's just called a 'framework'! Hopefully Sencha will continue to do such an excellent job of furthering ExtJS and make associations more robust.